# Syncing Two Divs Scrolls - TinyMCE & Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and added a direct preview in it, so on every key press, the preview gets updated with the data on TinyMCE. It looks like this:

[image]

However, even though everything seem setup and should adjust the height % of scrolls, it doesn't work. TinyMCE is failing to get the true heights.

---

I have re-created the issue on a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gm7j0e9u/3/

Try writing lots of lines so that div scrolls (and select `<pre>` from 'Formats' on TinyMCE for creating the problem better). You will notice that they do not sync. Please also take a look how I want it to behave on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b75KZ/5/)

---

The code:

```
setup : function(ed) {
   ed.on('init', function() {
      $('.editorContainer > .mce-tinymce > .mce-container-body').children().eq(2).on('scroll', function () {
         var tmceBody = ed.getBody();

         console.log("this offsetHeight: " + this.offsetHeight);   // 501
         console.log("this scrollTop: " + this.scrollTop);         // 160
         console.log("this scrollHeight: " + this.scrollHeight);   //  806

         var percentage = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight);
         console.log("this percentage: " + percentage);    // 0.5 -- Prev div works

         console.log("TMCE offsetHeight: " + tmceBody.offsetHeight);    // 1009
         console.log("TMCE scrollTop: " + tmceBody.scrollTop);          // 14
         console.log("TMCE scrollHeight: " + tmceBody.scrollHeight);    // 1037

         var x = percentage * (tmceBody.scrollHeight - tmceBody.offsetHeight);

         console.log("TMCE x: " + x);       // 14.2

         (tmceBody).scrollTop(x);
       })
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syncing preview div's scroll & tinymce's scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474841/syncing-preview-divs-scroll-tinymces-scroll)

Comment: @MichaelFromin That link is dead

Comment: @JonathanMichalik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489070/vertical-scrolling-sync-for-2-divs

Comment: Yes, I will tidy it up once I find the answer. It's a challenging topic and no answers.